# Determine the limits point of $x_n$?

Tags: real-analysis

> Determine  the  set  of the limit points  of $$x_n =  \left(\cos \frac{n\pi }{3}\right)^n$$

My attempt:   I think it will be $ \{-1,1\}$.

Is this true?

Comment: Why do you think it will be $\{-1,1\}$? What is your logic?

Comment: @YiFan  $-1 \le \cos x\le 1$

Comment: Note that $\cos(\pi n/3)\in\{1,\frac12,-\frac12,-1\}$ for integers $n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming the set of limit points refers to the set of the partial limits of the sequence $x_n$ so you can check for the following subsequences:

$n=6k\Longrightarrow x_k=\cos^{6k}{(2\pi k)}=1^{6k}\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}1$

$n=6k+1\Longrightarrow x_k=\cos^{6k+1}{(2\pi k+⅓\pi)}=\frac{1}{2^{6k+1}}\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

$n=6k+2\Longrightarrow x_k=\cos^{6k+2}{(2\pi k+2/3\pi)}=\big(-\frac{1}{2}\big)^{6k+2}\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0$

$n=6k+3\Longrightarrow x_k=\cos^{6k+3}{(2\pi k+\pi)}=(-1)^{6k+3}\underset{k\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}-1$

I'll leave for you to show $6k+4$ and $6k+5$ don't produce any new limit, so the set of partial limits is $\{-1,0,1\}$ since:

$$\cos{(3\pi/n)}=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}{-1} & {n \equiv 3\mod6} \\ {-1 / 2} & {n \equiv 2,4\mod6} \\ {1 / 2} & {n \equiv 1,5\mod 6} \\ {1} & {n \equiv 0\mod 6}\end{array}\right.$$

we have an answer for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ except $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, but we actually care about what happens as $n$ goes to infinity and not finite number of points at the beginning of the sequence.